# Create QT variables using for i in range

Tags: python, qt

I would like to create self variables using `for i in range`.

```
for i in range (1,50):
    name = "self.layoutG" + str(i)
    grid = QGridLayout()
    nameA = "self.layoutG" + str(i) + "a"
    gridA = QGridLayout()
```

I suspect this not a good way of doing it but I cannot predict how many `QGridlayouts()` I will need as it depends on the folder input the user puts in.

Will I be able to use these variables normally?

As after a number of tries it seems the variables don't seem to act the same way as stating the the variable names in a hardcoded way. I need to use variables in mutiple functions in the script which is why I've set them to self.

I am a beginner in QT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `dict`:

```
self.grids = {}   # dict
for i in range (1,50):
    self.grids[i] = QGridLayout()

# Get the 38th grid
grid = self.grids[38]
```

Comment: Thanks user2856 - will look into implementing that.  Whoops, yes I posted this in the wrong place, damn.

Comment: Just to report back- that worked and saved hundreds of line of hardcoding the parameters!